# How to remove first nbsp from TinyMce editor?

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I have a problem. When I edit page, I have:
`<p>&nbsp;</p>` on editor. When I remove empty line and save, does not matter I have this empty line. How I can fix it? My config:

```
editor.remove();
  editor = null;
  tinymce.suffix = '.min';
  tinymce.init({
    selector: 'textarea.richTextBox',
    language: 'ru',
    // skin: 'voyager',
    min_height: 600,
    resize: 'vertical',
    plugins: 'print preview fullpage searchreplace autolink directionality visualblocks visualchars fullscreen image link media template codesample table charmap hr pagebreak nonbreaking anchor insertdatetime advlist lists textcolor wordcount imagetools contextmenu colorpicker textpattern code',
    extended_valid_elements: 'input[id|name|value|type|class|style|required|placeholder|autocomplete|onclick]',
    file_browser_callback: function (field_name, url, type, win) {
        if (type == 'image') {
            $('#upload_file').trigger('click');
        }
    },
    toolbar: 'styleselect bold italic underline | forecolor backcolor | alignleft aligncenter alignright | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image table youtube giphy | removeformat | fullscreen | code',
    convert_urls: false,
    image_caption: true,
    image_title: true,
```

Example:

[image: Example image of problem]